# Runtime error on a validation rule?

Tags: apex, validation-rule, compound-fields

I encountered the strangest error today, and I wanted to make sure that this is a real thing and not just a silly mistake of mine.

I had a validation rule on `Lead`:

```
And( 
  isblank(Address), 
  $RecordType.Name = "Internal Leads" 
)
```

When creating a Lead object with only the `State` part of the address populated in a test class, I got the following error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation Formula "Validate_Address" Invalid (Programmer Error: Can't get an enum with a fieldId for a compound field): []

I'm completely aware of how to fix the problem, just split the Address field into its parts.  But I want to make sure I am right in interpreting what just happened.  **Is this in fact a runtime error when evaluating a validation rule?**

There is a trigger on lead which requires has some dynamic logic that references the schema, so it may explain the direction the error took, but it doesn't explain why it happened.

Comment: I am getting the same error and to make matters worse - it is only breaking in production when an unit test is trying to setup test data :D

Comment: Thanks for posting this, @SFDC Neuf.  Just had the same question and Google brought be here :) Long time no see

Answer (score 4):

> `Address` is a compound field that can only be accessed either from SOAP or REST API.

If you want to verify the Address attributes, you need to verify individual field components of `Address` Compound field.

Refer [Compound Field Considerations and Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000204592&type=1)

> Also refer, [restrictions in Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_validation_considerations.htm&type=0)(documentation):

- Compound fields, including addresses, first and last names, and dependent picklists and lookups
- Campaign statistic fields, including statistics for individual campaigns and campaign hierarchies
- Merge fields for auto-number or compound address fields such as Mailing Address

Comment: I confirmed that the doc does say exactly what [Santanu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/33230/santanu-boral) wrote above. What is amazingly strange is that for me the validation rule formula works fine in one Developer sandbox but not in a different Full sandbox. In the Full sandbox I get the same error reported in the question, "Programmer Error: Can't get an enum with a fieldId for a compound field".